# ошибка Target [Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Registrar] is not instantiable

Tags: laravel

Здравствуйте. Установил Laravel, настроил вьюшки, немного пописал в контроллерах, накатил миграции, все работает, но когда дошел до админки, не стал ничего изобретать, решил переделать существующий класс. Но сначала захотел проверить регистрацию и авторизацию. Перехожу по URL, где должен сработать редирект, меня успешно редиректит на страницу авторизации, но тут появляется ошибка:

> Target [Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Registrar] is not instantiable.

Выполнял команду `php artisan clear-compiled`, но не помогло 
Использую Ubuntu 14.04 
Версия Laravel 5.0

Comment: Очевидно, в DI не присутствует реализации Registrar

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в заключается в том, что по какой-то причине при установке Laravel были установлены не все файлы.

В первую очередь необходимо проверить, существуют ли следующие файлы:

```
app\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController.php
app\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController.php
app\Services\Registrar.php
```

Если они отсутствуют, то их можно скопировать из приложения Laravel, начисто установленного в другую папку.

Чтобы узнать, какая у вас версия Laravel, выполните следующую команду в корневой папке вашего приложения:

```
php artisan -V
```

После того, как файлы будут скопированы, необходимо выполнить команды:

```
php artisan clear-compiled
```

и

```
composer dump-autoload -o
```

Если изменений в проекте было сделано немного, возможно будет проще перенести свои наработки на заново установленное приложение.